# strange figures appear in the rendering

Tags: rendering

When I render, these figures appear.
Can someone help me?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have hidden model in your view port, because they won't be hidden in the render. To hide them in render, clic the camera icon on the left of the TV icon:[image]

Comment: to add to that. The random pattern on the side is called z-fighting.